# Connect() from ios to ios device in same subnet

Tags: iphone, ios, macos, arp

I develop IOS app, which needs to make standard TCP connection from one iPhone(or iPod) to another. Connection works well between apps on simulator and device, as well as between two simulators.

Application uses posix connect() and I have to stick to this method, because other modules are pure C.

When invoking connect() application blocks, and after timeout error is returned.
The communication is via wifi in LAN

I've sniffed the traffic and encountered, that after connecting to simulator, device sends ARP and after answer, standard TCP handshake proceeds and session is made.

Same case with iPhone<>iPhone stops after ARP request, because another iPhone doesn't respond to it. Moreover iOS sends only gratuitous ARP (announces it's mac ip pair). My MAC seems like proceeding this request, because its ARP table has iPhone record, it doesn't work for another iPhone.

I've tried bonjour service, but it also works only with simulator <> device.

My question:
Is there any way to allow such communication? Is it possible it is problem with my iPhones only? Is there any explicit way to tell OS to send response for arps, or is it somehow blocked for traffic ios<>ios communication.

Comment: I suspect ARP is a red herring. Can you elaborate on how you find the IP of the other device? Unless you use some broadcast packet prior to establishing the connection you can't really know the IP address of the peer device to connect to - for a wrong IP address the ARP fails by design.

Comment: In my example I know the IP of the other device, problem raises when I want to connect (it blocks, sends ARP(to iPhone) for mac of peer IP, and after no response -> timeout, it returns with error).
When connecting from MAC there is no ARP, because MAC caches ios gratuitous ARP messages, and it just sends SYN.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help, but I am working on a project that is doing something similar with devices announcing themselves on a network.  We are using SSDP to send out an alive request from one device and other devices are listening on the multicast address and port.  Once each device receives the alive, it sends out a response with all if its pertinent information, including IP Address and port.  Unfortunately, SSDP is a send and forget type of protocol, so there are issues there.  We use the IP Address and port information to send messages directly to each device.

Again, not sure if this helps in your situation, but I've seen this work very well so far.